# Is there a way to enalble public cache and disable private cache in the same time?

Tags: http, caching, header

We have enabled cloudfront caching.
In order to make cloudfront caching function we added `Cache-Control` header to respons on specific paths for example `example.com/page/1`. The response header includes:

```
cache-control: public, max-age=31556952
```

It seems thogh that by adding this header I have enabled browser's(private) cache as well, not just public cache (proxies, CDNs etc). The effect I would like to achieve is to have public cache working, but to prohibit private(Browser, user agent) caching. Is that possible? If yes - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The `public` directive [means](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.5) that "any cache MAY store the response".

It's hard to imagine a use case for allowing caching for every user (public cache) while at the same time disallowing it for any particular user (private cache).

Comment: It is possible to achieve per-user granularity caching on cloudfront(CF) via cookies.
So we are using session cookie + URL (kind of compound identifier) to cache user-specific views. But the browser cache doesnt respect this cookie and disrupts the proces. For example all "anonym user" (those who dont sent session cookie) are presented the same version of the page - that is ok. 
The problem is though that when signed-in user logs out she keep seing the subscriber page because the browser cache is hit and CF is not

Comment: @Hairi: I don't know what Cloudfront mechanism you're referring to, but standard HTTP caching already has a way to handle that, which is the [`Vary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary) response header. You should set `Vary: Cookie` on your user-specific responses, and then clear the cookie on the response to the logout request.